# How to solve $2\sin(\frac\pi 2 x - \frac \pi 6) + \sqrt3 < 0$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

**Problem**

Solve the trigonometric inequality: $$\displaystyle 2\sin\left(\frac\pi 2 x - \frac \pi 6\right) + \sqrt3  < 0$$

**My attempt**

I followed the usual steps, yielding

$$\frac\pi2 x + \frac\pi 6 < \arcsin(-\frac{\sqrt{3}} 2) = -\frac\pi3 + 2\pi n$$

which cleans up to

$$x < 4n-\frac23, \ \ \ n\in\mathbb Z$$

However, this doesn't seem to coincide with Wolfram Alpha's answer, which is

$$4n - 1 <x< \frac13(12n - 1)$$

Did I forget a step? Or am I missing some theory here?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

[image]
$$x\in \left( -\left( \pi +\arcsin { a+2\pi n }  \right) ;\arcsin { a+2\pi n }  \right) $$

Answer (score 1):

You should have $$-\frac{2\pi}{3}+2n\pi<\frac{\pi x}{2}-\frac {\pi}{6}<-\frac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi$$

$$\implies -\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi<\frac{\pi x}{2}<-\frac{\pi}{6}+2n\pi$$
$$\implies-1+4n<x<\frac 13(-1+12n)$$